# Only one organic group id / name is shown in content listing

Tags: 7, views, organic-groups

I want to create a block/page with a general content listing of all the content in the different organic groups.

Problem is the specific nodes only show **one group id / group name** even though it **belongs to multiple groups**.

To show the group name I used 'OG membership: Group Node from OG membership' relation.

Is there a way to do is with basic view functions. I suppose it can be done using a PHP field but I prefere the basic methods if they exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution: Include 'Content: group audience'